# Trying to make AI use a target priority system

Tags: java, swing, jframe, artificial-intelligence

I have made an AI for an Agar.io copy, and the AI follows the nearest cell that is smaller than it an tries to eat it, however I want to make it follow a nearby cell based on priority, so it is not necessarily the closest cell to the AI e.g: the closest cell to the AI is smaller than one that is slightly farther away that is much larger, choose the larger cell instead based on it having a higher priority score due to its mass.

Here is my code. (if you need the full class, [here is the entire class on pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/eEhe9rjM))

```java
public void Update() {
        if (this.mass > 3500) {
            this.mass = 3500;
        }
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            if (this.checkCollide(cell.x, cell.y, cell.mass) && this != cell && this.mass > cell.mass + 10) {
                if (1 / (this.mass / cell.mass) >= .4 && this.mass < 4000) {
                    addMass(cell.mass);
                }
                respawn(cell);
            }
        }
        if (!isPlayer) {
            if (goalReached) {
                if (returnNearestCell() > -1) { // No Cell Found
                    if (!isTarget) {
                        target = cells.get(returnNearestCell());
                        isTarget = true;
                        targetType = "c";
                    } else if (isTarget && targetType.equals("c")) {
                        targetType = "n";
                        isTarget = false;
                    }
                } else if (returnNearestCell() == -1) { // Cell Found
                    if (!isTarget) {
                        pTarget = Particle.particles.get(returnNearestP());
                        isTarget = true;
                        targetType = "p";
                    } else if (isTarget) {
                        targetType = "n";
                        isTarget = false;
                    }
                }
                goalReached = false;
            } else {
                double dx = 0;

                double dy = 0;
                if (targetType.equals("c")) {
                    if (returnNearestCell() > -1) {
                        target = cells.get(returnNearestCell());
                        dx = (target.x - this.x);
                        dy = (target.y - this.y);
                    } else {
                        goalReached = true;
                    }
                } else if (targetType.equals("p")) {
                    pTarget = Particle.particles.get(returnNearestP());
                    dx = (pTarget.x - this.x);
                    dy = (pTarget.y - this.y);
                } else {
                    goalReached = true;
                }
                double distance = Math.sqrt((dx) * (dx) + (dy) * (dy));
                if (distance > 1) {
                    x += (dx) / distance * speed;
                    y += (dy) / distance * speed;
                } else if (distance <= 1) {
                    goalReached = true;
                }

            }
        } else {
            double dx = (goalX - this.x);
            double dy = (goalY - this.y);
            this.x += (dx) * 1 / 50;
            this.y += (dy) * 1 / 50;
            // addMass(10);
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE: this is what I've written so far for the priority system, which I can then call in the Update() function, however I am clueless at this point on what to do next. .**

```java
    public int targetPriority() {
        int priority = 0;
        int distance = 0;

        int mass = 0;

        List<Cell> possibleTarget = null;

        int aPriority = 0;
        int bPriority = 0;
        int cPriority = 0;

        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            mass = cell.mass / 10;

            distance = (int) Math.sqrt((this.x - cell.x) * (this.x - cell.x) + (cell.y - this.y) * (cell.y - this.y));
            priority = distance - mass;

            for (Cell A : possibleTarget) {
                for (Cell B : possibleTarget) {
                    for (Cell C : possibleTarget) {
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        return priority;
    }
```

Comment: You've posted a desire, a goal and some code, but you've not posted a specific and answerable question. You're obviously trying to implement some functionality with this code -- have you tried to implement this yet? If so, where is this attempt, what is its result, and what is causing you trouble? If not, best if you delete the question, and then re-open it after you've shown your attempt. Also best to post a valid [mcve] with your question. Please read the link as it will explain what I'm requestion, and more importantly it will explain how a well-crafted MCVE can help you get a decent ans.

Comment: Also, as per site rules, no links to pastebin please. All relevant code should be in your question.

Comment: Well, my attempt is that it only follows the nearest cell that is smaller than it, however, I am not sure on how to make it follow a nearby cell based on its mass and distance from the player in comparison to the nearest cells distance and mass.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the mentioned problem using a **scoring system**, for each nearby agent give it a score based on its distance and size, and then insert the score for the agent in a priority queue based on the score.

for example: suppose you have 3 nearby agents A, B and C
A: 1m distance & 4 Size
B: 2m distance &1 Size
C: 5m distance & 8 Size

assuming they're all smaller than you then they would be scored based on the difference between distance and size as follows:

```
A-->3
B-->1
C-->3
```

A & C are equal-->pick the closest one

**this a simple solution to the problem, but a real solution would be using a heuristic function and determine what is the best path to be chosen**

look at [heuristic](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

Comment: Sizes get quite big, so would I like divide the size by 10 to add that to the score? just so distance isnt insignificant compared to size for the score.

Comment: in fact, that depends on the scale between size and distance, if you see that better then give it a try you'll not lose anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your scoring. . is it A = size - distance? because then b  != size - distance because that would equal -1 not 1.

Comment: Hey I added the "UPDATE:" section to this post, would you be able to help me out?